# Fill PDF from Nodejs API app hosted on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, pdf, azure-api-apps

Is there a way to fill pdfs on nodejs app without using a C or C++ library? I am wanting to fill pdfs stored on my server based on data stored in a database. I have seen several solutions such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdffiller and https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-fill-form.

However, all of the pdf fillers I have seen are wrappers around some C or C++ library. My backed is hosted on Azure as an Azure API app. As far as I know of, C and C++ libraries cannot be installed on my API app. If they can, I can use one of the above pdf fillers but how would I install the library on Azure when I only see the option of deploying code from git repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure coffee/javascript module [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) you can leverage with to implement the operations of generate or edit PDF files.

Please try the following code sample:

```
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit"),
    fs = require("fs");

var doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
doc
   .fontSize(25)
   .text('Hello World!', 100, 100)
doc.end();
```

I have tested on Azure Web Apps server, it works fine on my side.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.